# whether the quotient of continued fraction of algebraic irrational number is bounded or not is similar or equivalent to Collatz conjecture?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, computability-theory, continued-fractions

I vaguely recall that whether the quotient of continued fraction of algebraic irrational number is bounded or not is similar or equivalent to Collatz conjecture, could any one give the reference? or proof?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the only similarity is that no one has any idea how to settle either of them.

Comment: More specifically, they're both particular instances of problems whose generalisations are $\Pi^0_2$-complete.

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher good, but possibly there are much deep link.

Comment: The continued fraction for $\log 3/\log 2$ comes up in Sinisalo, On the cycle length of the Collatz sequence, www.probleme-syracuse.fr/cargo/Sinisalo_collatz.pdf but that's not what you want if for no other reason than that that number isn't algebraic. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172476/what-are-possibilities-to-disprove-the-collatz-conjecture and http://www.mathematics.pitt.edu/sites/default/files/Martiny%2020-min-grad.pdf and http://d-scholarship.pitt.edu/24817/1/Masters_-_Collatz.pdf and http://www.darrellcox.website for more of the same.

Comment: Both problems are questions about the dynamics of certain transformations, though very different ones: Collatz conjecture is about the behavior of natural numbers under the Collatz map (discrete situation), while continued fractions are basically analysis of the map $\frac{1}{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}$ (continuous operation) on the set of algebraic numbers (which is somehow "discrete algebraically", but indiscrete topologically). Is this perhaps what you meant?

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher I don't know much about complexity but I'm looking at an attack on Collatz which uses the set $\omega^{<\omega}$. Is there any fairly instant insight into whether that will be "strong enough" to attack a $\Pi^0_2$-complete problem?

Comment: @Wojowu there is a perhaps slightly closer analogy than yours between the two, which is that $1-1/\lvert x\rvert_2 x$ converges for all rationals where $\lvert x\rvert_2 x$ means divide out the powers of $2$.  This unites the continued fraction representation with the $/\langle2\rangle$ quotient. Proof is linked here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2855057/334732